# Saving crop image with laravel

Tags: php, forms, image, laravel, base64

I started learning laravel, and attempt to make a website with it. I'm trying implement "uploading a crop image". I'm using croppie https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ and manage to successfully displaying on the browser.

Now, I want to save the image to the database. I'm struggling at this stage, I've spent hours searching and trying but it doesn't seem to work. I've read that laravel doesn't use the patch method to send crop images as well as I need ajax. Can someone help me how I would get the **base64** from the form. This is my form:

```
<form  action="{{route('program.updateImage', ['id'=> $program->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div id="crop" class="croppie-container">

    </div>
    <a class="upload-file">
      <span>Upload</span>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="upload"><br>
    </a>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save image">
</form>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::patch('program/image/{id}', 'ProgramController@updateImage')->name('program.update');
```

Code for croppie

```
$(function() {
    var basic = $('#crop').croppie({
      viewport: {
        width: 400,
        height: 200
      },
      boundary: { width: 400, height: 300 },
    });
    basic.croppie('bind', {
      url: '{{asset('images/'.$program->image)}}'
    });
  });

  function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#crop').croppie('bind', {
          url: e.target.result
        });
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $('.upload-file input').on('change',function(){
    readFile(this);
  });
```

and my function:

```
public function updateImage(Request $request, $id){
    //$this->validate($request, array('image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png'));
    $program = Program::find($id);

    //list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    //list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);

    //$data = base64_decode($data);




    echo $request;

}
```

Comment: is you get base64 string

Comment: Your mentioned code with `Code for croppie` has syntax error for url

Comment: Yes, I've realised I have lots of errors in my code, I manage to fix them and got the functionality I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here jquery code for upload image

```
   $('#crop_img_upload_button').on('click', function (e) {
        var image_data = $('#crop').croppie('result', 'base64');
        if (image_data != '') {
            var formData = $('#crop_it_form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "uploadUrl",
                data: formData, 
                cache: false,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    //response here
                }
            });
        } else {
           // validation msg here
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting data from the controller, im using $request->input( 'data' ); is this right?

Comment: I used this as  base and did some tweaks here and there and finally got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To get `base64` of image use this :

```
var base64 = $('#crop').croppie('result', 'base64');
```